Can processor read the cache line directly with an invalidation for this line in the invalidation queue?
In "Memory Barriers: a Hardware View for Software Hackers", there is a classical scenario to demonstrate how the invalidation queue works in Section 4.3.
However, I am a bit confused: is there any mechanism like Store Froward for the invalidation queue?
The scenario in Section 4.3 can be simplified as follows:

P0 writes A, thus it sends an invalidation to P1 and puts the write into the store buffer;
P1 put the request in the queue, with a stale value for A stay at it cache line;
P1 read A directly from its cache line, despite the existing invalidation entry in the queue.

I saw that a CPU reads directly from the cache line even if there is a corresponding invalidation in its invalidate queue(Section 4.3, Steps 8 and 9) and processes the invalidation queue afterward.
I can verify the point with the invariant of the coherence rule, as the latest value has not been written to the cache line.
The 'read despite the queue' does not retrieve a literal stale value as no 'newer values' exist on any processor's cache line (it is in the store buffer).
However, I am still confused about the question of whether the processor reads the cache line directly even if an invalidation exists in its invalidate queue.
I thought it was somewhat 'counter-intuitive' as there is a 'store forward' mechanism on the other hand.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51264290/memory-barriers-a-hardware-view-for-software-hackers-invalidate-queues this question should address your question.

Is that paper purely theoretical or it's supposed to describe some architecture? It's possible to build a CPU with an invalidation queue that's weakly ordered w.r.t. its cache but that's not how some real CPU work (e.g. Intel's ones).

@MargaretBloom thank you and I believe the paper is mostly theoretical. But do you mean that some Intel CPUs load from invalidation queue before from the lines?

@AmadeuszLiu thank you thats quite similar but I believe it still is different

Intel's CPU use RFOs to transit a shared line into the exclusive state. And, AFAIK, no stale read can occur (even if intermediary caching agents ack the RFO early, acting as an invalidation queue). That's why reading and writing the same line in different cores lead to it being "bounced" back and forth the two.
